# jquery and css rendering different based in the same browser window based on whether loaded via django or statically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a strange situation. For a web page written using html, jquery and css, on the same browser but in 2 different tabs, I am getting different renderings of the page.

Case 1: Loading the html file directly from the file system: In this case the code renders correctly. This code uses $window.width() which returns 2273. The code also uses setTimeout() and $timeout to perform certain jQuery operations after the DOM is loaded

Case 2: Serving the html/images/css from a django site (locally hosted): In this case $window.width() comes out to be 2067. Some of the jQuery portions don't work well. All images and the overall page is "bigger" in size.

Same browser (Chrome) different tabs.

Any clues?

Comment: So one tab is loaded with `file://...` and the other with `http://localhost/...` right? And does the difference only happen when you have both tabs open, or also when you load only one at a time?

Comment: Correct. Even when I have a single tab open

Comment: Are you sure you have the same zoom factor on both pages? 2273/2067 is exactly 110%. Otherwise I'd look into cross domain issues. WRT the paths of the files used, what may look to be a different domain to the browser on the web server may be OK on the file system, or vice versa.

Comment: The code is exactly the same on the file system and the web server. I am using Django to host. 110 % is a good observation. Where would the zoom factor be specified? CSS? Also, all files are on the same domain but even if some were on a different domain, why should cross domain affect the width?

Comment: I meant the user zoom factor. You know, Ctrl++. (In Chrome, there is a small magnifying glass icon in the location bar when you are at a different zoom level than 100%.) And about the cross-domain issue, maybe there could be css or javascript files that change the font-size for html. If those file aren't loaded because they are on an untrusted domain, the font-size won't get changed! Just make sure that can't be the problem.

Comment: I will check the zoom factor but I doubt that's the issue. Do you think it could be an issue due to the copious use of setTimeout() in the jQuery part of the code? I think the developer was attempting to have the DOM loaded and then do the jQuery operations, such as window.width(). Since the files coming from the web server take more time, it's possible that there is a race condition.

Comment: Hm. I can't see the files from here, so I couldn't say if it was something like that. But yes, like I said, if a file isn't loaded, it will result in different results than if it can be!

Comment: Thanks - I will try to find a way to post the code, at least a part of it.

Comment: I reduced the zoom factor and that fixed it. For some reason Chrome must be remembering the zoom factor by the URL location bar. Thanks.

Comment: @MrLister  Please put your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If text and images look bigger on one page than on another, while they shouldn't, the zoom factor is the first thing you should check.

It's easy to quickly zoom in or out a bit with the keyboard, and then to forget about it, but Chrome has per-page zoom settings, so that when you revisit a page that you once zoomed in on, it will use the same zoom factor again.

And of course, to a browser a page at `file:///var/www/file.html` is not the same page as the one at `http://localhost/file.html`, even if you know they are.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips.  For my case, this issue happens in firefox. And it is actually a new page I open. But zoom out  indeed solve the problem.